# php 2d array sorting by column Priority

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have some x,y coordinates  data which am trying to sort by axis priority , i tried sorting data with array_multisort() function however i noticed that it only target one column

xy sample data array

```
$xy_dat_ray = array(
  array('x' => 111.0, 'y' => 17.83),
  array('x' => 25.83, 'y' =>  10.37 ),
  array('x' => 37.85,'y' => 13.57 ),
  array('x' => 17.13, 'y' => 41.33 ),
  array('x' => 13.64, 'y' => 16.35 ),
  array('x' => 99.16, 'y' => 34.74),
  array('x' => 12.495, 'y' => 66.855 )
);
```

if i use array_multisort like

```
array_multisort(array_column($xydata, 'x'),array_column($xydata, 'y'), $xydata);
print_r(array_shift($xydata));
```

am getting

> ```
> [x] => 13.495
> [y] => 66.855
> ```

however i want to be strict with y column ,  like  minimum Y values are (10.37,13.57,16.35,17.83)  so i want that i get

> 'x' => 13.64, 'y' => 16.35

because in case of y = 10.37  x is 25 which is not minimum there are low values of x ,  in case of y = 13.57 x is 37.85 which is high , however in case of 16.35 x is 13.64   which is ok , because min Y values like ( 10.37 , 13.57 ) had big x value 
so any idea how to solve this problem in php

code sample::           [CODE DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2421b49eaaf49422291242442768bad275da09ba)

Answer (score 0):

ok solution was simple :)

just sum up  x and y values and load them to another array let say $sum_ray;

then find minimum value in that sum array by index  like

```
$min_val_index = array_keys($sum_ray, min($sum_ray));
```

then you got that min x and min y exact pair  ...  like

```
print_r($xy_dat_ray($min_val_index[0]));
```